# log_file in tcl Expect strucks for long fast output

Tags: ssh, tcl, expect

I have this code to ssh to device and using expect , i log_file all the output of command. The command returns about 2000 lines of output very fast. 1/2 times , the output gets struck and never ends , unless i kill the ssh process in the unix

```
             proc SSHSendCommand {args} {

      array set aArgs $args
      # supported options
      #  -spawn_id       (required)
      #  -cmd            (required)
      #  -timeout        (optional.  Default=60s)
      #  -buffer_size    (optional.  Default=2000)
      #  -log            (optional.)

      if {$aArgs(-spawn_id) == 0} {
        puts ": got spawn_id of \"0\".  Not logged in."
        return ""
      }
      # set default value for timeout
      if {![info exists aArgs(-timeout)]} {
        set aArgs(-timeout) 60
      }

        if {[info exists aArgs(-log)]} {
        log_file -noappend $aArgs(-log)
        }

      # flush the expect buffer
     if {[catch {expect {
        -timeout 1
        -i $aArgs(-spawn_id)
                    -re {.*} {}  }
                 } sError ]} {
        # caught error, connection may have been lost and shut down
        puts "WARNING: Caught error in : $sError"
        return ""
      }

    if {[catch {

        # send the command
        exp_send -i $aArgs(-spawn_id) "$aArgs(-cmd)\r"
        set sResponse ""

          # wait for the command prompt to return
          expect {
            -timeout $aArgs(-timeout)
            -i $aArgs(-spawn_id)
            -re {#} {}
            timeout {puts "Timed out waiting for command prompt to return";  
              return ""                   
}
          }

      } sError]} {
        # caught error
        puts "WARNING: caught error during :  $sError"
        set sResponse ""
      }
      log_file
      # return the response text
      return $sResponse
    }
```

The time of command output finishes in 5 seconds mostly .., timeout is given 60 secionds

Comment: Is the pattern {#} getting matched? Is there a buffer overflow: check https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/exploring-expect/9781565920903/ch06s18.html and http://wiki.tcl.tk/9407

Comment: Yes, its matched it works half the times, half the times, my output gets struck

Comment: Enable debug mode and see what is expect matching against. https://www.pantz.org/software/expect/expect_examples_and_tips.html  exp_internal 1